# Understanding the trace of 3 matricies

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

https://i.stack.imgur.com/FT9jH.jpg

I'm a little confused by this question (really new to Linear Algebra so haven't done much complex). I know the trace is the sum of diagnol values in a matrix ((1,1), (2,2), (3,3)) etc.

I also know that tr(A+B) = tr(A)+tr(B). With that knowledge, I read this previous post to learn how also tr(AB) = tr(BA) [$[A,B]=AB−BA$. Show that for all square matrices, $\operatorname{trace}([A,B])=0.$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3001637/a-b-ab%E2%88%92ba-show-that-for-all-square-matrices-operatornametracea-b-0).

I'm not sure how to solve this question - multiple answers can be right here. I need to show some work, but I'm thinking tr(ABD)=tr(BDA)=tr(DAB) since tr(AB)=tr(BA).

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Prove the fourth option,

$$
\operatorname{tr}(ABD)=\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{k=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^na_{ij}b_{jk}d_{ki}\;,
$$

from the definitions of the matrix product and the trace, and then use that to prove the second option,

$$
\operatorname{tr}(ABD)=\operatorname{tr}(DAB)=\operatorname{tr}(BDA)\;,
$$

the cyclic invariance of the trace (which you can also prove using $\operatorname{tr}AB=\operatorname{tr}BA$, as you suggest, in case you’re allowed to use that).